# Use external libraries in erlang application

Tags: erlang, zeromq

In my Erlang application I want to use external library (erlzmq2). I am a newbie to erlang and don't know how to package it or compile it. Currently I am using rebar for compilation, if the answer is based on editing rebar.config file it would be more useful to me.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily for you, your library appears to be rebar-packaged, because it's got a `rebar.config` in the root of its repo: https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2

Assuming you have no dependencies configured yet, you'd just add this to your own `rebar.config`:

```
{deps, [
   {erlzmq2, "2.*", {git, "git://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2", {tag, "2.1.11"}}}
]}.
```

This works to add the "2.1.11" release.  You could also just work against head:

```
{deps, [
   {erlzmq2, "3.*", {git, "git://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2"}}
]}.
```

The format of a "deps" entry is

- Name of the application, as seen in its x.app file ([erlzmq2.app.src line 1](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2/blob/2.1.11/src/erlzmq.app.src#L1))
- A Regex matching the "vsn" from its x.app file ([erlzmq2.app.src, line 4](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2/blob/2.1.11/src/erlzmq.app.src#L4)). You can use ".*" if you want to bypass this sanity check.
- A tuple giving the location where the dependency can be fetched from.  In the case of `git`, you can give it a `branch` or `tag` tuple in addition to the URL.

---

Packaging up your application with Rebar and Reltool is a whole new question, I think, and a complex one at that.  But if your application is fairly small/one-off/informal, you might try Rebar's "escriptize" command.

If your application is "foo", you'll need a `foo.erl` in src that has the appropriate `main/1`.  Then add to your `rebar.config`:

```
{escript_incl_apps, [erlzmq2]}.
```

and from the command line (after getting reps and compiling), run

> rebar escriptize

Rebar will stuff all your binaries and those of the "encrypt_incl_apps" into a single file that runs as an executable.

Comment: what will be the third field (tuple) when the library is located in local file system ? Is /lib/. the ideal location to put up external libraries ??

Comment: Have you made local modifications? Are you on a system where 1k of disk space is precious? Are you on a system without network access? If none of these are the case, I recommend using the standard Rebar practice of referencing the remote library.

Comment: okay I will use standard practise of referencing. I am able to successfully build erlzmq with my application. But when I reference it in my code like "Context=erlzmq:context()" it terminates by complaining 'module could not be loaded'. I suspect it is some linkage issue , do u have any idea how to run this properly ?

Comment: I feel like you're straying into new-question territory, because this is now asking how to package an application, right? I've updated my answer with a shortcut solution for little applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some more additional information, you can create a seperate folder named lib and export the lib path to ERL_LIBS if this is not rebar compatible. If the library is good enough you can put the same in OTP lib directory but that is not recomended!